# Webpack watch mode not working with html-webpack & clean-webpack plugins

Tags: javascript, webpack

When I run Webpack with watch mode (not using the dev server), everything will build correctly the first time, but when I change any of the code that isn't the HTML file, the HTML file won't be rebuilt since it wasn't changed and so clean-webpack-plugin decides that it's a stale asset and deletes it along with all of its dependencies. How can I fix this? Do I have to get rid of clean-webpack-plugin?

My webpack.config.js:

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const mode = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

module.exports = {
    mode,
    watch: mode === 'development',
    entry: {
        popup: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'ts', 'popup.ts')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: ['ts-loader', 'eslint-loader'],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: ['file-loader'],
            }
        ]
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'popup.html'),
            filename: 'popup.html',
            chunks: ['popup'],
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin({
            patterns: [{
                from: 'src/manifest.json',
                transform: function(content) {
                    return Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({
                        description: process.env.npm_package_description,
                        version: process.env.npm_package_version,
                        ...JSON.parse(content.toString())
                    }));
                }
            }]
        })
    ],
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    }
};
```

Comment: Same issue here. Not sure, but it's likely due to changes in version 4 of html-webpack-plugin. The combination html-webpack-plugin@3.2.0 and clean-webpack-plugin@3.0.0 works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you your index.html file doesn't get regenerated in each rebuild (which from the options above doesn't look like it), you have to add set the  `cleanStaleWebpackAssets` option to `false` clean-webpack-plugin.

```
new CleanWebpackPlugin({cleanStaleWebpackAssets:false})
```

https://github.com/johnagan/clean-webpack-plugin#options-and-defaults-optional